# ¿Cómo renombrar las variables de un data frame usando una tabla de nombres viejos y nuevos?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo un data.frame `datos` con nombres cortos de variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(v1 = sample(18:65, 
            size = 20, 
            replace = TRUE),
           v2 = sample(c("femenino", "masculino", "otro/no binario", "prefiero no responder"), 
            size = 20,  
            replace = TRUE, 
            prob = c(0.44, 0.44, 0.1, 0.1)), 
           v3 = sample(c("Primaria completa", "Secundaria Completa", "Universidad Completa"), 
            size = 20, 
            replace = TRUE)) -> datos
```

También tengo un diccionario de variables en el que, para cada nombre de columna en datos, hay una etiqueta larga que coresponde a la pregunta que se hizo en el cuestionario (mis datos son de una encuesta).

```
data.frame(nombre = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), 
           etiqueta = c("¿Cuál es tu edad en años cumplidos?", 
                        "Con qué género te identificas", 
                        "¿Cuál es el máximo nivel de escolaridad que has alcanzado?")) -> diccionario
```

Quiero encontrar una forma simple para poder renombrar a datos usando a las etiquetas como nombres. Esto porque en ocasiones estoy haciendo un gráfico o una tabla y para hacerlos más comprensibles prefiero la descripción y no el nombre corto.

La solución que uso es `colnames(datos) <- diccionario$etiquetas`. Esto funciona si están todas las columnas de `datos`, en el orden original y no hay columnas nuevas. Pero generalmente quiero cambiar los nombres justo a último momento antes de generar un gráfico o tabla y para entonces es probable que ya no esté trabajando con todas las variables, haya creado unas nuevas o haya cambiado el orden.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría generar una solución ad-hoc, pero es mejor definir una función que cambie los nombres y sea muy fácil de usar.

La función `renombrar()` toma como primer argumento un data.frame, por lo que es fácil de usar en tuberías, y como segundo argumento a otro data frame con el diccionario. Para mantenerla simple en el desarrollo y en el uso hay que tener la precaución de que el diccionario tenga siempre dos columnas llamadas `nombre` y `etiqueta`, aunque estos nombres se podrían cambiar en la definición de la función (pero no en la llamada, ver más abajo).

Vamos a generar un test para asegurarnos de que el resultado sea el esperado. En este caso no están todas las columnas, no tienen el mismo orden y hay una columna nueva.

```
datos |>
  select(v2, v1) |>
  mutate(`Año de nacimiento` = 2022 - v1) -> datos_test
```

La función recibe dos argumentos, el primero es el data.frame cuyos nombres se van a cambiar y el segundo el diccionario. Por defecto el diccionario se llama `diccionario`, así que si le damos ese nombre a data frame con los pares de nombres y etiquetas no tenemos que pasar el argumento explícitamente.

```
renombrar <- function(df, dic = diccionario) {
#Como voy a usar un join tengo que pasar los nombres de df a data.frame
  nombres = enframe(names(df), name = "id", value = "nombre")
#Con left_join empato a los nombres presentes en df con los que están en el diccionario. 
# Si una columna no está entonces no se empata y que NA. Además quedan ordenados.
  etiquetas = left_join(nombres, dic, by = "nombre") |>
# Si hay una columna nueva (que no está en diccionario) el join me dará NA. 
# Con coalesce() recupero el nombre en el df original para que siempre coincidan los largos.
    mutate(etiqueta = coalesce(etiqueta, nombre))
# Con el vector etiqueta preparado es cuestión de asignarlo a colnames    
  colnames(df) <- etiquetas$etiqueta
  df
}

datos_test |> 
  renombrar()
```

Si quisieras no depender de unos nombres fijos en `diccionario` y tener una función a la que puedas parametrizar y asignar nombres arbitrarios para las columnas con nombres y etiquetas la solución es mucho más complicada, al menos conceptualemente. La complicación la introduce la evaluación no estándar de `tidyverse`. El problema es que las funciones enframe, left_join y coalesce toman argumentos de maneras muy diversas. Por ejemplo, enframe toma como primer argumento unos datos que se evalúan en un nombre (name) y otros luego dos que tienen que ser cadenas de caracteres. Algo parecido pasa con left_join. `coalesce()` recoge los argumentos con `...`, así que ahí a fuerzas tiene que haber una expresión no evaluada o una lista que podamos convertir en tal cosa.

Las opciones entonces serían buscar una solución con R base en la que no dependamos de funciones que reciben nombres si encomillar como argumentos o meternos de lleno en la evaluación no estándar y usarla todo lo posible para simplificar el problema.

Eso es lo que hace `renombrar2()`. Usa dos operadores de `rlang::` importados por `dplyr` para resolver el problema. El primero es `{{}}` que captura una expresión y la inyecta y evalúa como argumento de función que recibe nombres como argumentos. `!!!`, que "empalma" una lista y la abre como expresiones que sirven de argumentos en `...`

```
#Modifico el diccionario para cambiar los nombres de columnas.
diccionario |>
  rename (name = nombre, label = etiqueta) -> diccionario2

renombrar2 <- function(df, 
                       dic = diccionario, 
                       viejos = nombre, 
                       nuevos = etiqueta) {
  nombres <- dic |>
    select({{nuevos}}, {{viejos}}) |> 
    deframe() 

  rename(df, !!!nombres[nombres %in% names(df)])
}

renombrar2(datos_test, dic = diccionario2, viejos = name, nuevos = label)
```

La función toma 4 argumentos: el data frame al que vamos cambiar los nombres, el data frame con el diccionario de variables, el nombre de columna en el diccionario con los nombres viejos (deben coincidir con al menos algunos de los nombres de df) y el nombre de la columna en en diccionario con las etiquetas o nombres nuevos. Al especificar nuevos y viejos no importa el orden que las columnas tengan en diccionario.

Seguramente hay alguna solución más simple.

Fuentes:

La documentación `rlang::` en https://rlang.r-lib.org/ es la fuente más concisa y práctica que he visto para entender y usar evaluación no estándar con dplyr. Más concisa y más práctica no quiere decir que sea concisa o práctica.

El capítulo sobre metaprograming de Advanced R expone muy bien los conceptos fundamentales y los por qué de este estilo de metaprogramación, pero es muy enredado en las explicaciones y menos orientado a la práctica que las viñetas de rlang.

En [esta respuesta de akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493635/how-to-rename-columns-in-a-table-by-using-a-table-of-old-and-new-names-in-r-tid) ví el truco de `rename(!!!vector_nombrado)`.

Answer (score 1):

Esta muy bien tu solución por ser "tidy/pipe compatible" y usar técnicas avanzadas e interesantes que no conocía del todo, pero si puedo, me gustaría darte una alternativa, aunque sea código R base. Lo primero que cambiaría, es la forma en que manejas el diccionario, un vector o una lista, a mi criterio, es más parecido al concepto de diccionario, voy a tomar tu `data.frame` para convertirlo en un `vector`, estándar:

```
dict <- setNames(diccionario$etiqueta, diccionario$nombre)

dict
                                                          v1 
                       "¿Cuál es tu edad en años cumplidos?" 
                                                          v2 
                             "Con qué género te identificas" 
                                                          v3 
"¿Cuál es el máximo nivel de escolaridad que has alcanzado?"
```

Con esta estructura, podemos armar un función que creo es bastante flexible, aunque habría que implementar algún control para validar los datos de entrada:

```
rename_cols_from_dict <- function(x, dict) {
  cols <- setNames(colnames(x), colnames(x))
  change <- na.omit(dict[cols])
  cols[names(change)] <- dict[names(change)]
  setNames(x, cols)
}
```

Como está definida, puede también usarse dentro de un pipe:

```
datos_test |>
  rename_cols_from_dict(dict)
```

Comment: Es una solución más directa y con menos dependencias, en ese sentido es mejor. Trabajo con el diccionario de variables (la idea de diccionario de variable la tomo de SPSS, no de los lenguajes que tienen la estructura diccionario) como data.frame por dos motivos. 1) Se me hace mucho más fácil crearlos, editarlos y almacenarlos como un .csv en lugar manejar código que genera un vector. Obviamente es posible almacenar como .csv y convertirlo a vector al inicio del script o dentro de esta misma función. La penalización de desempeño no debe ser muy alta.

Comment: 2) con el diccionario en un df puedo hacer este mismo cambio en datos pivotados largos con join. Es cuestión de empatar los nombres de columna. Trabajo mucho con datos largos, así que me simplifica las cosas tener una única estructura para renombrar. De todos modos admito que la segunda versión es exagerada, pasa que me había clavado con metaprogramación y quería ver si servía para esto.

Comment: Sin duda para trabajar en un lote "tidy" un `data.frame`  es la mejor solución y a veces incluso como es en el caso de tu respuesta hace las cosas más entendibles.. Al menos para mí, me resulta más fácil de asimilar a primera vista un `left_join` que un el matching tradicional entre vectores  como estoy haciendo en mi respuesta.